# How to plot dictionaries with different keys in the same plot?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

Suppose I have two dictionaries in Python which might have different lengths and whose not all keys of one are in the other.

For example consider that the first dictionary has keys `k1` and measurements `m1` and the second `k2` and `m2`. For example:

```
#1st dictionary
k = ['2015_05_06', '2015_05_26', '2016_03_03']
m1 = [10, 8.5, 19]
#second dictionary
k2 = ['2014_05_06', '2015_05_06', '2016_03_03']
m2 = [10, 13, 9]
```

If I do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(k1, m1)
plt.plot(k2,m2)
plt.show()
```

The result is the following[image]

Basically the x-axis  which represents dates is not ordered and thus the second plot is plotting in the wrong x-axis position.

To solve this situation I thought to create a set of unique values such as:

```
 k = list(set(k1+k2))
```

but then the `k` and `m1` and `m2` have not the same length.

Is there a smart way to plot dictionaries with different keys in the same plot so that the keys on the x-axis are correctly ordered
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to turn your dates into a datetime object.

```
from datetime import datetime

d1 = [datetime.strptime(x, '%Y_%m_%d') for x in k]
d2 = [datetime.strptime(x, '%Y_%m_%d') for x in k2]

plt.plot(d1, m1, d2, m2)
```

Since the datetime objects maintain a complete order, your plot will be ordered too, but it will also reflect the different durations between each time step.
[image]

Comment: Being inside a loop,  can I do 2 separates plot? like `plt.plot(d2, m2)`, `plt.plot(d2, m2)` and then `plt.show()`?